# Eclipse, short way to initialize object via setters

Tags: java, eclipse, rad

For example I have the following object:

```
public class Dog{
    private String name;
    private int age;
    private int legs;
    private Color color;

    /*getters and setters*/
}
```

And I want to initialize it and set all properties not by constructor but by using setters:

```
Dog dog = new Dog();
dog.setName("Rex");;
dog.setAge(4);
...
```

Can I generate code which set all fields from above in the easy way?

Comment: `dog.setName = "Rex";` Won't work. Do you mean `dog.setName("Rex");`?

Comment: Yes, of course. I'll fix it, thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to automatically generate getters and setters in Eclipse?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7221691/is-there-a-way-to-automatically-generate-getters-and-setters-in-eclipse)

Comment: The easiest way is to use a constructor. Why don't you want to use one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's cumbersome, but what I do:

> Use Eclipse's *Source -> Generate Getters and Setters...* function (also `ALT + SHIFT + S`) and then just replace all  '=' characters with '(' and ';' with ');'. finally I go through every line and press `ctrl-space` to let Eclipse finish the method call with proper casing (configure Eclipse to *overwrite* instead of *insert* code assist suggestions).

That or do a regex replacement if it is *a lot*.

Comment: Try using ALT + SHIFT + S and select "generate getters and setters" from prompt menu.

Comment: Yeah that's a time-saver for sure

Comment: Thank you! Your answer is more close to what I've been looked for.

Answer (score 0):

You can introduce a `setAllValues` method, that should take all the attributes of your class as parameters. And simply call the setters inside that method.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new template in eclipse in Preferences/Java/Editor/Templates and then just use it (similar to 'syso' ctrl+space that produces System.out.println)