# Setter/getter code template

Tags: java, eclipse, xcode-template

Is there a better way to create a "code template" for Eclipse that generates at the same time the property and getter/setter?

I can't find any way to camel the property name in the setter and getter code

```
private ${propertyType} ${propertyName};
public ${propertyType} get${PropertyName} ()
{   
    return ${propertyName};
}
public void set${PropertyName} (${propertyType} ${propertyName})
{
    this.${propertyName} = ${propertyName};
}
```

Is there any well done code repository on the web?

Any "code template" reference?

Comment: Why can't you just use the [built in function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7221691/is-there-a-way-to-automatically-generate-getters-and-setters-in-eclipse)

Comment: Ask **one** question per question. *"Is there any well done code repository on the web?"* would be **way** to broad a question for SO.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by, "camel the property name"?

Comment: @nitind The property is named "foo", but the methods need to capitalize it to get "getFoo". He meant camelCase the method name.

Comment: @chancea the builtin function is very useful in a post production context when you want to create set and getter for a lot of parameters, "code template" is useful when you are writing code on the fly.
Please notice that the camelCase problem (thank @IngoBürk) will occur to solve a lot of other powerful templates