# Returning multiple integers in one method

Tags: java, class, methods

```
// set date of birth
    public void setDOB(int day, int month, int year)
    {
        this.day = day;
        this.month = month;
        this.year = year;
    }

    // get date of birth
    public int getDOB()
    {
        return day;
        return month;
        return year;
    }
```

Why do I get an error when I try to return these three values? I thought I was able to do something like this in order to save some space by not writing each set/get method for day, month, and year.

Also, I only seem to get an error with `return month;`, meaning it's the only one that eclipse has highlighted to tell me to delete it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot return multiple values with return statements same time. When the first return statement executes the remaining two statements become unreachable.

Possible solutions

1) Return an array

2) Return a list of int's

3) Or construct an object and return it.

When you wrote `getDOB()`  that should be a Date object, not an int. It seems you need to return a Date object there.

Answer (score 2):

You cant. The first return statement will end the method and return control to the caller. Further returns will never be reached. You can only return a single value from any method, and you specified the return type as int.

Comment: So I'm going to have to just create set/get methods for each?

Comment: @Onikouzou yes you have to create separate set/get methods for each. if you are using eclipse, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7221691/2431281) could help you

Comment: @Onikouzou to be honest, this particular case I would recommend you to use an existing Date class rather than roll your own. Google for JodaTime.

Answer (score 1):

> Why do I get an error when I try to return these three values?

Return type `int` means your method will `return` `int` only and once return statement executed your other code becomes *dead* after the return statement because after `return number;` control directly goes to the *caller* of the method.

You should return `Date` in your case, as it's all about `Date` of birth.

Moreover, you can have three different `getter` methods instead (*not recommended in your case*).

```
public int getDay(){ return day;}
public int getMonth(){ return month;}
public int getYear(){ return year;}
```