# Convert "auto property" in C# to Java alternative code

Tags: java, c#, selenium

I am new to Java and currently trying to follow along a  `"Selenium Automation Framework"` course. Unfortunately, the tutorial is in C#. I got stuck with a piece of code in C# and not able to convert it to Java alternative code. From my understanding,

`public static IWebdriver Instance { get; set; }` is a auto property which is not available in Java. Any suggestions, greatly appreciated?

```
package WordpressFramework;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class Driver {

public static IWebdriver Instance { get; set}

    public static void Initialize()
    {
        WebDriver Instance;
        Instance=new FirefoxDriver();
        Instance.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);  
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java has no properties then you can use [get/set methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjbbp.html). Also it'll be better to change name from nonsensical "instance" to "webDriver".

```
private static IWebdriver webDriver;

public static IWebdriver getWebDriver() {
    return webDriver;
}

public static void setWebDriver(IWebdriver webDriver) {
    Driver.webDriver = webDriver;
}
```

Comment: In Java selenium jar, IWebDriver interface is defined as WebDriver

Comment: A static method wouldnt have a `this` reference?

Answer (score 1):

IWebDriver interface is defined as WebDriver in Java.

```
public class Driver {

    private Webdriver webDriver;

    public static Webdriver getWebDriver() {
        return webDriver;
    }

    public static void setWebDriver(Webdriver webDriver) {
        this.webDriver = webDriver;
    }
}
```

In eclipse you just need to declare a private variable and use eclipse's code generation capabilities to generate getters and setters.

> Right click -> Source -> Generate setters and getters

Reference: [Is there a way to automatically generate getters and setters in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7221691/is-there-a-way-to-automatically-generate-getters-and-setters-in-eclipse)

Answer (score 0):

Drop the get/set, and just leave:
`public static IWebdriver Instance;`

It will be a member variable instead of a "property".

Answer (score 0):

This piece of C# code:

```
public static IWebdriver Instance { get; set}
```

Is a simplified way of declaring variable and set getter and setter compare to Java.

Comment: From which version Java has properties with set and get?

Comment: @AlexButenko I should update my answer. I meant `public static IWebdriver Instance { get; set}` in C# is a simplified way of declaring setter and getter compare to java.

Comment: Oh, I was confused by your previous answer. I thought Java finally get it :)