# Is there a way to auto generate boilerplate code for pojo mapping without hiding implementation in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-boot, ide

I want to see the full code, but I don't want to hand write the mapping.
I don't want to minify or hide the pojo mapping (I know tools like lombok will do this for me).

Comment: Eclipse might have something similar to this:  In NetBeans I can define fields then chose to auto-generate the setters and getters.  I think that's what your looking for (it makes actual source code, not generates them through some extra process).  See if the IDE has a menu to auto generate code, it might be there.

Comment: What do you mean by "POJO mapping"? If you mean getters and setters, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7221691/is-there-a-way-to-automatically-generate-getters-and-setters-in-eclipse

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about mapping two similar beans, for example your DTOs to your Spring entities? If so I'd say look into Dozer.